# Basic window with Tkinter, mainloop()

Tags: python, class, tkinter, mainloop

I am quite new to Python and currently learning how to create basic windows using Tkinter.

The Python documentation suggests using the following code (simplified):

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Window, self).__init__(master)
        self.master =  master

root_window = Tk()

application_window = Window(root_window)
application_window.mainloop()
```

On the other hand, some tutorials I watched on the topic, suggest using

```
root_window = Tk()

application_window = Window(root_window)
root_window.mainloop()
```

What is the correct way of using `mainloop()`? If both of them are correct, what should preferably be used?

Comment: @BryanOakley Oh,I misread it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter, the code works identically in either way. Most code I've seen calls `mainloop` off of the root window.